# Problems while using an SSD. Some HDD and SSD partitions fail to mount

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, ssd

I just added a new SSD drive and copied all the root files to it, edited fstab and updated the grub. Now the system is booting but some partitions fail to mount including 1 SSD partion and the swap partition which is in the old HDD.

During boot I get this error : `The disk drive for UUID=731f3b08-ae9f-4e0e-ae1e-ef89e2acbc2e is not ready or not present.` also get a similar message for `/mnt/SSDData`. How can I fix this?

My fstab :

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=53a51f96-91a8-40fe-9001-e23b5345648d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2ACD-F70C  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=05f57dcf-0d25-48e6-b10f-22403207f548 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=731f3b08-ae9f-4e0e-ae1e-ef89e2acbc2e none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/04E03BAEE03BA4B8 /mnt/Data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data,x-gvfs-icon=Data 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/B2C6D17DC6D14271 /mnt/B2C6D17DC6D14271 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/13b5fbd9-9f8e-495e-abe8-36dec9db8e9d /home/SSD auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=SSD,x-gvfs-icon=SSD 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2066a69f-8284-4c83-8bfd-9c33453255b8 /mnt/SSDData auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=SSDData,x-gvfs-icon=SSDData 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5c612d17-386b-4c04-9bc3-b1b27a46955a /mnt/SSDData auto defaults 0 0
```

The blkid output :

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="53a51f96-91a8-40fe-9001-e23b5345648d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="5c612d17-386b-4c04-9bc3-b1b27a46955a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="44C8CBF8C8CBE670" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="2ACD-F70C" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdb4: UUID="B2C6D17DC6D14271" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="B4EAD41CEAD3D8A6" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="caef6612-a2b3-440a-833c-18b3317cf461" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb7: UUID="05f57dcf-0d25-48e6-b10f-22403207f548" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb8: UUID="179768ad-16ec-4c94-b9a1-cf1d12736dbc" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb9: LABEL="Data" UUID="04E03BAEE03BA4B8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb10: UUID="9688d65f-5b72-434d-b5dc-688aeec47756" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb11: UUID="f2af0b4d-3c39-41a5-ab5a-75d291c1fb14" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Did you double-check the UUIDs? (Did you re-partition?) Please print the output of `blkid`.

Comment: @Sparhawk just added the blkid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `blkid`, you can see that the UUIDs have changed. Perhaps this occurred after you re-partitioned?

For example, `blkid` shows

```
/dev/sdb8: UUID="179768ad-16ec-4c94-b9a1-cf1d12736dbc" TYPE="swap"
```

i.e. the swap partition is now `179768ad-16ec-4c94-b9a1-cf1d12736dbc`. Make a backup, then change the relevant line in `/etc/fstab` from

```
UUID=731f3b08-ae9f-4e0e-ae1e-ef89e2acbc2e none            swap    sw              0       0
```

to

```
UUID=179768ad-16ec-4c94-b9a1-cf1d12736dbc none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I'm not sure which of the other partitions belong where, but do similar modifications for the other ones that fail.

---

Also, I'm not sure if it'd work anyway, but you might as well be consistent with your formatting. i.e. instead of

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2066a69f-8284-4c83-8bfd-9c33453255b8 ....
```

use

```
UUID=2066a69f-8284-4c83-8bfd-9c33453255b8 ....
```

---

### EDIT

Now I look at it, from the last two lines of `/etc/fstab`, it seems that you are trying to mount two partitions to `/mnt/SSDData`? Presumably `sda` is your SSD and consists of `/` and `/mnt/SSDData` in that order? If so, then remove the second-last line of `/etc/fstab`. (And clean it up as per my above instructions.)

Also, the third last line of `/etc/fstab` makes reference to `13b5fbd9-9f8e-495e-abe8-36dec9db8e9d`, which is not in `blkid`. OTOH, there are some extra partitions in `blkid` that are not in `/etc/fstab`, so I'm not sure if you wanted to change that `/etc/fstab` to the proper UUID, or just delete it.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it. What about the `mnt/SSDData` ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not update the uuid for your swap partition, and instead of updating the uuid for the other one, you added a duplicate entry.